# Ошибка ImportError: dlopen() при переносе скомпилированного файла на другое устройство Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, mac, pyqt6

После переноса файла .app на другое устройство выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/boss/Desktop/RuTracker.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 161, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/boss/Desktop/RuTracker.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 84, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, "exec"), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/boss/Desktop/RuTracker.app/Contents/Resources/RuTracker.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/boss/Desktop/RuTracker.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.11/PyQt6/QtWidgets.abi3.so, 2): Symbol not found: _NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua
  Referenced from: /Users/boss/Desktop/RuTracker.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.11/PyQt6/Qt6/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/A/QtCore (which was built for Mac OS X 10.14)
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Users/boss/Desktop/RuTracker.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.11/PyQt6/Qt6/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/A/QtCore
```

Компилировал с помощью py2app на Python 3.11. На устройстве, где происходила компиляция, файл открывается нормально, а на другом ошибка.

Данный файл существует в каталоге программы

Как от нее избавится?

Comment: Вы под виндой запускаете? Там написано (which was built for Mac OS X 10.14)

Comment: @Виктор Запускаю на моноблоке Apple с системой Mac OS

Comment: У Вас всё в одном файле? Просто пишет что нет QtWidgets.abi3.so. Я бы Pyinstaller использовал - тем более с ним QT собирается на раз в один файл

Comment: @Виктор Да, я никакие изменения во время компиляции не вносил. Возможно дело в библиотеке PyQt6, но я не понимаю что не так. Файл полученный перемещал по пк, запускался как и должен, а при переносе выдает ошибку при запуске

Comment: Скопируйте, для начала, QtWidgets.abi3.so туда, куда скопировали Ваше скомпилированное приложение. Какой размер файла получился после сборки?

Comment: @Виктор данный файл и так находиться в каталоге программы. И попытка его заменить никаких плодов не дала. Файл вышел размером в 267 мб. Как понимаю там весь Python в нем, из-за чего такой большой вес.

Comment: Попробуйте всё же через pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole src.py. Предварительно установив upx, для уменьшения размера раза в 2. Я всё делаю через виртуальное окружение, а Вы?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140607/discussion-between-otets-valerian-and-).